# ethers.js how to call overloaded function with enum argument

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, enum

Ethers generally doesn't let you call an overloaded function like this `contract.overloaded(1)`, but it does let you call it with a fully qualified function name like this `contract["overloaded(uint)"](1)`. However, I now have a function that takes an `enum` as an input, and I don't know how to do a fully qualified function call for that. Consider the example contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;


contract MyContract {
    enum MyEnum{ ZERO, ONE}

    function unique(MyEnum _enum) public view returns(uint) {
        if (_enum == MyEnum.ZERO) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    function overloaded() public view returns(uint) {
        return 0;
    }

    function overloaded(MyEnum _enum) public view returns(uint) {
        if (_enum == MyEnum.ZERO) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can call non-overloaded functions or overloaded functions that don't have `enum`s as arguments (both return 0, showing that the `enum` input in the unique function is parsed correctly):

```
const ethers = require("ethers");
const MyContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyContract");
myContract = await MyContract.deploy();
await myContract.deployed();

console.log(await myContract.unique(0));
console.log(await myContract["overloaded()"]());
```

However, if I try calling the overloaded function with an `enum` argument like this

`console.log(await myContract["overloaded(MyEnum)"](0));`

or like this

`console.log(await myContract["overloaded(enum)"](0));`

I always get errors like **`TypeError: myContract.overloaded(MyEnum) is not a function`** or **`TypeError: myContract.overloaded(enum) is not a function`**. I couldn't find the syntax for calling overloaded functions in the [ethers documentation](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/) either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer - `enum`s are treated as `uint8` internally by solidity, so `myContract["overloaded(uint8)"](0)` works. Leaving this here in case it helps anyone.